# Angular compile in directive seems to go into infinite loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive with dynamic text. I want to be able to have ng-click directives to call functions from the text. I understand the best way to do this is to compile the html into a template. But when I try to do this I get into an infinite loop:

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('times', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.selectDay = function() {
          console.log("Clicked on directive");
        }

        var content = element.html("<div><span ng-click='selectDay()'>Some test content</span></div>");
        var compiled = $compile(content);
        element.append(content);
        compiled(scope);        
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "call functions from the text"? I wonder if manually calling `$compile` is unnecessary...

Comment: @MichalCharemza I mean I need to generate the html based on certain conditions by concatenating strings. The strings I use for the html have buttons in that need to be clickable and call a function on the main scope.

Comment: What are the conditions? Can you expand the code in the question a little bit to show what you mean? (My aim is to see if what you want can be done in the template of the direcrive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the way you are compiling. First give the element the content, and then compile its content with the scope:

```
element.html("<div><span ng-click='selectDay()'>Some test content</span></div>");
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seyenaz/HB7LU/11553/)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with you were compiling wrong element after appended it to DOM,
You should first compile the new element with scope and then append to the directive element

**CODE**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.directive('times', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.selectDay = function() {
        console.log("Clicked on directive");
      }

      var content = "<div><span ng-click='selectDay()'>Some test content</span></div>";
      var compiled = $compile(content);
      element.append(compiled(scope));
    }
  };
}]);
```

[**Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MjrZlz85FaFmpqbwy8UD?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way, like this:

```
angular.module('app').directive('times', [
    '$compile',
    function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div><span ng-click="selectDay()">test</span></div>',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                return scope.selectDay = function() {
                    return console.log('Clicked on directive');
                };
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: I need to update the html of the template, can I do that from the directive itself?

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-order your content creation and compilation.
Create the content, then create the compile function, then compile and then append the compiled content. DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/d2ayw9vz/

```
angular.module("app",[])
  .directive('times', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.selectDay = function() {
          console.log("Clicked on directive");
        };

        var content = "<div><span ng-click='selectDay()'>Some test content</span></div>";
        var compiled = $compile(content);
        var linked =compiled(scope);    
        element.append(linked);



      }
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: This version still sends me into an infinite loop

Comment: @Tom Strange, I don't see a loop in the fiddle example. Are you looking at the example or is the loop in your updated code?

Comment: I didn't see the fiddle, that's in my updated code. I'm struggling to see the part in my code that changes it though.